# How to concatenate the preprocessor constant and a literal string in cout

Tags: c++, macros

I started to learn c++, and when I tried to cout a macro it prints the value in the console but when I tried to cout the macro with another string literal, it raises an error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define PI 3.14;
int main()
{
    cout<<"Value of PI: " << PI;
    cout<<"Value of PI: " << PI << endl;
}
```

First-line inside the main function works perfectly, but the second line raises an error while compiling.

Error:

> error: expected primary-expression before '<<' token
> cout<<"Value of PI: " <<PI<<endl;

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: fwiw, in both cases you try to print `PI` and a string literal. The difference is the `<< endl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have a semicolon at the end of the macro.

This line

```cpp
cout<<"Value of PI: " << PI << endl;
```

then becomes:

```cpp
cout<<"Value of PI: " << 3.14; << endl;
//                           ^
```

So, just remove the `;` at the end of the macro:

```cpp
#define PI 3.14
```

---

You could also use a proper constant instead of a macro (which is usually preferred):

```cpp
inline constexpr double PI = 3.14;
```

or use the [mathematical constants](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/constants) library part that was added in C++20:

```cpp
#include <numbers>

int main() {
    std::cout<<"Value of PI: " << std::numbers::pi << '\n';
}
```

Comment: or `static const auto PI = 3.14;`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yeah, I added some options